# Dojo Examples work but mine doesnt

Tags: javascript, dojo, menubar

So I was practicing and it runs when I click it, however when i copy and paste it into my own word processor (Atom) and run it in a tab, its just blank

```
require([
"dijit/MenuBar",
"dijit/PopupMenuBarItem",
"dijit/Menu",
"dijit/MenuItem",
"dijit/DropDownMenu",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(MenuBar, PopupMenuBarItem, Menu, MenuItem, DropDownMenu){
var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({});
var pSubMenu = new DropDownMenu({});
pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "File item #1"
}));
pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "File item #2"
}));
pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
    label: "File",
    popup: pSubMenu
}));
var pSubMenu2 = new DropDownMenu({});
pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Cut",
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"
}));
pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Copy",
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy"
}));
pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    label: "Paste",
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste"
}));
pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
    label: "Edit",
    popup: pSubMenu2
}));
pMenuBar.placeAt("wrapper");
pMenuBar.startup();
});
</script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

There is no issue with the backslash being a period.

Comment: Are you loading `dojo.js` somewhere before the script above is executed?

Comment: Im sorry I am very knew and I just used this from a sample code. This was all that was given. There was no dojo.js.

Answer (score 0):

To actually get something runnable, you'll need a bit more than just the code snippet posted in the question. At the very least you'll need to load the Dojo loader (`dojo.js`) or an equivalent AMD loader -- that's where the `require` function comes from. Since the code is creating a menu using Dijit, you'll also want to load the base Dojo stylesheet and a Dijit theme (otherwise the menu will look pretty terrible).

The main [Dojo website](http://dojotoolkit.org) has a number of tutorials. The [Hello Dojo!](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html) one is a great way to get started.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
  <script>
    require([
      "dijit/MenuBar",
      "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem",
      "dijit/Menu",
      "dijit/MenuItem",
      "dijit/DropDownMenu",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(MenuBar, PopupMenuBarItem, Menu, MenuItem, DropDownMenu) {
      var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({});
      var pSubMenu = new DropDownMenu({});
      pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "File item #1"
      }));
      pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "File item #2"
      }));
      pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
        label: "File",
        popup: pSubMenu
      }));
      var pSubMenu2 = new DropDownMenu({});
      pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Cut",
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut"
      }));
      pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Copy",
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy"
      }));
      pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Paste",
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste"
      }));
      pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
        label: "Edit",
        popup: pSubMenu2
      }));
      pMenuBar.placeAt("wrapper");
      pMenuBar.startup();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```